# Java App on Mac asking for allow network connections everytime

Tags: java, macos

My Java.app broadcasts a packet on the network as soon as it starts up. Everytime I start this app, the Mac asks me do I want to allow network connections blah..blah.. Can I use info.plist or something to allow network access to this app and not bother the user who has trustingly downloaded and installed my app.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can choose to `allow incoming connections` for specific services in `System Preferences` > `Security` > `Firewall`.

Addendum: You application will appear only if the user has chosen to "Set access for specific services and applications." It will be added the first time the application attempts to open the port.

Addendum: The application appears with the name `java` in the `Firewall` pane. Once the user chooses to accept or deny, the dialog ceases to appear. This simple [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3245805/230513) is convenient for testing.

Comment: -ve. The problems

 1) I want to allow this for all users of my software.
 2) I can not find by App in the System Preferences -> Security -> Firewall.

Comment: 1) Not sure about all users; 2) more on "specific services" above. Is the first part of your comment missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you codesign your app (using the same key across updates) it should work properly with the app-specific firewall on.  It seems to be a bug on Apple's side that unsigned java apps are prompted for allowing network connections (even if they don't try to listen to the network) every time they are run.